# How to find a density matrix of a qubit?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

If we are given a state of a qubit, how do we construct its density matrix?

Comment: Related: [Density matrices for pure states and mixed states](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/density-matrices-for-pure-states-and-mixed-states)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're given $|\psi\rangle$, just calculate $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$.

For example, $|\psi\rangle=\cos\theta|0\rangle+\sin\theta e^{i\phi}|1\rangle$, then $\langle\psi|=\cos\theta\langle 0|+\sin\theta e^{-i\phi}\langle 1|$. This means that
$$
\rho=\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\theta\\ \sin\theta e^{i\phi}\end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta && \sin\theta e^{-i\phi}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos^2\theta & \cos\theta\sin\theta e^{-i\phi} \\ \cos\theta\sin\theta e^{i\phi} & \sin^2\theta
\end{array}\right).
$$