# How to prepare a statistical mixture of $|0,0\rangle $ and $ |1,1\rangle $ in QuTiP?

Tags: quantum-state, programming, qutip

A QuTiP novice here. It's easy to prepare a pure state in QuTiP. For example, to prepare $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0,0\rangle + |1,1\rangle)$:

```
psi = (ket('00') + ket('11')).unit()
psi = (tensor(basis(2,0), basis(2,0)) + tensor(basis(2,1), basis(2,1))).unit()
```

But what code would you use to prepare a statistical mixture of $ |0,0\rangle $ and $ |1,1\rangle $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixed states are represented by [density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) cf. [Density matrices for pure states and mixed states](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/density-matrices-for-pure-states-and-mixed-states?noredirect=1&lq=1). [This](http://qutip.org/docs/3.1.0/guide/guide-states.html#density-matrices) is the QuTiP documentation for density matrices; check the 4th example. The [`ket2dm`](http://qutip.org/docs/3.1.0/apidoc/functions.html?highlight=ket2dm#qutip.states.ket2dm) function takes input a ket or bra vector and returns density matrix formed by the outer product. So say for a 50-50 mixture the following code should work:

```
from qutip import *
0.5*ket2dm(tensor(basis(2,0), basis(2,0))) + 0.5*ket2dm(tensor(basis(2,1), basis(2,1)))
```

This returns the required density matrix representing a 50-50 statistical mixture of $|0,0\rangle$ and $|1,1\rangle$.

```
Quantum object: dims = [[2, 2], [2, 2]], shape = (4, 4), type = oper, isherm = True
Qobj data =
[[0.5 0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.5]]
```