How many observables do we need to confirm a qubit state?
Suppose I have many copies of a qubit in the pure state $\vert\psi\rangle$. How many distinct observables do I need to choose to determine that I indeed hold $\vert\psi\rangle$?
For example, if $\vert\psi\rangle=\vert 0\rangle$, then checking $\langle 0\vert Z\vert 0\rangle = 1$ by doing many $Z$ measurements seems enough. This suggests if one has some idea of what the state might be, then one observable will do to confirm or deny this.
Secondly, if the state is unknown, is knowing $\langle \psi\vert X\vert \psi\rangle, \langle \psi\vert Y\vert \psi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi\vert Z\vert \psi\rangle$ enough? Is there a higher-dimensional analogue too?

You want to read up about "quantum state tomography".

Nielsen and Chuang have a section on quantum tomography.

Thanks, I see that for an unknown state, one indeed measures $X, Y$ and $Z$ expectation values. However, is it true that if one of those expectation values is 1, then I know the state without even trying the others? That is, if $\langle \psi \vert Z\vert\psi\rangle=1$, then $\vert\psi\rangle = \vert 0\rangle$?

see eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9089/55

Yes in some cases fewer observables might be enough. Eg $\langle\psi|Z|\psi\rangle=1$ is theoretically enough to certify $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle$ (assuming infinite precision of the estimate etc). In higher dimension it's not that simple though, and you'll need more values. I think the generalisation of that statement is if you have a pure state whose expectation value wrt a given $O$ is extremal, meaning it saturates the boundary in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/425101/58382. Though there might be partially flat pieces of boundary that affect this
